# Why the below code is not writing the string "Write this to the file" to the File "my_file"

Tags: node.js, file, callback, fs

I wrote the below code to write the string "Write this to the file" to the file "my_file". Up on execution the I get "FileWrite Completed Successfully" on the console -- from the callback of the fs.write. But I see nothing in the File.

```
var fs = require('fs');

function openFileAndAppend(writeBuffer){
    fs.open('./my_file','a',function opened(err,fd){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            fs.close(fd,function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("Problem in closing the file upon the Open;");
                }
            });
        }
        var bufferOffset = 0;
        var bufferLength = writeBuffer.lenght;
        var filePosition = null;
        fs.write(fd,writeBuffer,bufferOffset,bufferLength,filePosition,function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("FileWrite Completed Successfully");
            fs.close(fd,function(err){
                console.log("Closing the file");
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("Problem in closing the file after the write");
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

openFileAndAppend(new Buffer('Write this to the file'));
```

Please help in finding the error.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error after posting this question:

There is a typo in  var bufferLength = writeBuffer.**lenght;**

Thank You